# Why did old cars have really long throw shifters?

Tags: manual-transmission, theory, shifter

What was the reason that old cars had very long throw shifters and that modern cars now have much shorter throw shifters? For example even old sports cars like the urmodell generation of 911 had very long throw shifter but newer 991 992 etc generation of 911s have much shorter throw shifters.

Comment: I don't know the answer for sure, but I'll bet it has something to do with the need for more torque in the shifting process to get it from one gear to the next.

Comment: Yeah, old clunky gearboxes need more leverage to shift the gears. I remember the stick on my BMC Mini was about 2 feet long - but that was partly because of where the geabox was situated.